# How to encapsulate method to print console out to Word

Tags: python, automation, docx, data-analysis

I want to print my summary stats sometimes to console, and also other times to Word.

I don't want my code to be littered with lines calling to Word, because then I'd need to find and comment out like 100 lines each time I just wanted the console output.

I've thought about using a flag variable up at the front and changing it to false when I wanted to print versus not, but that's also a hassle.

The best solution I came up with was to write a separate script that opens a document, writes by calling my first summary stats script, and then closes the document:

```py
import sys
import RunSummaryStats
from docx import Document

filename = "demo.docx"
document = Document()
document.save(filename)
f = open(filename, 'w')
sys.stdout = f

# actually call my summary stats script here: Call RunSummaryStats etc.
print("5")

f.close()
```

However, when I tried doing the above with `python docx`, upon opening my docs file I received the error `We're sorry, we can't open this document because some parts are missing or invalid.` As you can see the code above just printed out one number so it can't be a problem with the data I'm trying to write.

Finally, it needs to go to Word and not other file formats, to format some data tables.

By the way, this is an excerpt of RunSummaryStats. You can see how it's already filled with print lines which are helpful when I'm still exploring the data, and which I don't want to get rid of/replace with adding into a list:
[image]

Comment: So, this is not how you actually use the `python-docx` package. You've created an empty document, and then you're overwriting that by piping `sys.stdout` to the file buffer.  Assuming this is some sort of logging output, why not just use plain .txt file?

Comment: It needs to go to Word to create some tables, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you modify the summary function to return a list of string? This could easily be dumped into the document e.g., via `for item in summary_stats: document.add_paragraph(item)`.

Comment: Which version of Python? If we're Python 3, you could create your own `io.IoBase` subclass that appends to an encapsulated `docx.Document` on each write operation.

Comment: ...that said, it would be much easier to just write to a `cStringIO` object, and then dump *that* into a `Document` later.

Comment: "just write to a cStringIO object, and then dump that into a Document" I might try to do this and update this post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy thing is to let `cStringIO` do the work, and separate collecting all your data from writing it into a file. That is:

```
import RunSummaryStats
import sys

# first, collect all your data into a StringIO object
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
stat_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stat_buffer
try:
    # actually call my summary stats script here: Call RunSummaryStats etc.
    print("5")
finally:
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout

# then, write the StringIO object's contents to a Document.
from docx import Document
filename = "demo.docx"
document = Document()
document.write(add_paragraph(stat_buffer.getvalue()))
document.save(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks very much Charles. This is the kind of solution I was hoping for. Unfortunately, when I write `try: RunSummaryStats` my stats from there still get printed to the console. `print("5")` from this module works fine. I don't know if sys.stdout is refreshed when I run another module or any other backend behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `Document()` [constructor essentially creates the .docx file package](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html) (this is actually a .zip archive of *lots* of XML and other stuff, which later the Word Application parses and renders etc.).

This statement `f = open(filename, 'w')` opens that file object (NB: this does not open Word Application, nor does it open a Word Document instance) and then you dump your stdout into that object. That is 100% of the time going to result in a corrupted Word Document; because you simply cannot *write* to a word document that way. You're basically creating a plain text file with a docx extension, but none of the underlying "guts" that make a docx a docx. As a result, Word Application doesn't know what to do with it.

Modify your code so that this "summary" procedure returns an iterable (the items in this iterable will be whatever you want to put in the Word Document). Then you can use something like the [`add_paragraph`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document.add_paragraph) method to add each item to the Word Document.

```
def get_summary_stats(console=False):
    """
        if console==True, results will be printed to console
        returns a list of string for use elsewhere
    """
    # hardcoded, but presume you will actually *get* these information somehow, modify as needed:
    stats = ["some statistics about something", "more stuff about things"]
    if console:
        for s in stats:
            print(s)
    return stats
```

Then:

```
filename = "demo.docx"
document = Document()

# True will cause this function to print to console
for stat in get_summary_stats(True):
    document.add_paragraph(stat)
document.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe there was a better way to do it, but in the end I

1. created a single function out of my summary stats script `def run_summary`
2. created a function based on @Charles Duffy's answer `def print_word` where `StringIO` reads from `RunSummaryStats.run_summary(filepath, filename)`
3. called `def_print_word` in my final module. There I set the variables for path, filename, and raw data source like so:

`PrintScriptToWord.print_word(ATSpath, RSBSfilename, curr_file + ".docx")`

I welcome any suggestions to improve this or other approaches.